# PHP account system

Tags: php, database, authentication, fetch, account

I have a complicate question which I can't find answers from online, or maybe I just don't know the best word to describe it,but hopefully you all and help out little bit, thanks you so much.

I want to create a user account system in php

I know how to store user date when they registra an account in form, but next time when people log in how do you know whether they has an account already or not, other words how do you validate their username and password when they come to your side.

Answer (score 1):

You must store the users data they provide on sign up, using a database such as [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) or a flat-file system such as [this class](http://lukeplant.me.uk/resources/flatfile/).

May I suggest you search up tutorials etc. using Google or Bing, if you look hard enough you can find anything on the internet ;)

You can always try this out - PHP Login

Dom.

Ps- check out [PHPSquad](http://phpsquad.net/), [Tizag](http://tizag.com/phpT/) and [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/) they helped me massively when first learning PHP!

Comment: Sorry for not posting proper hyperlinks, but apparently I need 10 rep to post more than 2 :/ - you should be able to copy/paste them right into your address bar though.

Comment: You should be able to use http://www.tizag.com (`http://www.tizag.com`) etc. which will automatically make a clickable link ;-)

Comment: @fred - Yeah but the site restricts you to two properly formatted links until you have 10+ rep :)

Comment: Ah, ok. Maybe I should just edit your answer ;-) that'll work.

Comment: Thank you all so much for answering, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use SQL database to store the users so you have to create a register page to insert the user data into the SQL database then a login page to read the user data from the database and you can make a profile page with the data you asked to the user on the register form you can do this with ASP and PHP I recomend you PHP cause is easier.

[Here is a link](http://slunked.com/user-registration-and-login-system/all/1) that shows how to make a simple user registration system with PHP and MySQL but you have to add some security to your system.

Comment: Thank you all so much for answering, I got it.